# summarise function in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I am trying to create a R database including some numerical variable.
While doing this, I made a typing mistake whose result looks weird to me and I would like to understand why (for sure I am missing something, here).

I have tried to look around for possible explanation but haven' t found what I am looking for.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

 data <- 
  data.frame(FS = c(1), FS_name = c("Armenia"), Year = c(2015), class = 
  c("class190"), area_1000ha = c(66.447)) %>% 
  mutate(FS_name = as.character(FS_name)) %>%
  mutate(Year = as.integer(Year)) %>%
  mutate(class = as.character(class)) %>%
  tbl_df()

data

x <-  data %>% 
  group_by(FS, FS_name, Year, class) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(area_1000ha = sum(area_1000ha, rm.na = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

As you can see, the mistake is 
    rm.na= 
rather than 
    na.rm=
When I type correctly, I have the right result on area_1000ha variable (10.5).
If I don't - i.e. keeping rm.na= I get 11.5, instead (+1, in fact).
What am I missing?

Comment: `sum` first argument is `...` which match any arguments not otherwise matched, so any _valid_ argument not match with `na.rm` will addup to the sum; check the following examples `sum(1,2,a=3,rm.na = TRUE);sum(1,2,a=3,rm.na = 'A');sum(1,2,3, na.rm = TRUE)`. Read more about `...` [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

I think `rm.na=TRUE` is added to the sum, and as TRUE is considered as 1, it sums your initial sum and 1.
If you change TRUE to 2 for example

```
x <- data %>% 
  group_by(FS_name, Year, class) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(area_1000ha = sum(area_1000ha, rm.na = 2)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The result is

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  FS_name  Year class    area_1000ha
  <chr>   <int> <chr>          <dbl>
1 Rome     2018 class190        12.5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in R as rm.na hence R is considering it as a variable which has value TRUE i.e. 1.

Try keeping it na.rm = T and you will get the right result.

Even if you change the name of the variable

```
x <-  data %>% 
  group_by(FS, FS_name, Year, class) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(area_1000ha = sum(area_1000ha, tester = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I have replaced rm.na with tester variable.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  FS_name  Year class    area_1000ha
  <chr>   <int> <chr>          <dbl>
1 Rome     2018 class190        11.5
```